# Can a Mongodb aggregation project a single subdocument from a subdocument array based on date?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

Assume a collection of People, each with an collection of location subdocuments, some which include "future" locations:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name": "Homer", "itinerary": [ { date: "...", "location": "Springfield" }, { date: "...", "location": "London" } ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "name": "Bart", "itinerary": [ { date: "...", "location": "Las Vegas" }, { date: "...", "location": "Houston" } ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "name": "Marge", "itinerary": [ { date: "...", "location": "Washington" }, { date: "...", "location": "Springfield" } ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "name": "Lisa", "itinerary": [ { date: "...", "location": "London" }, { date: "...", "location": "Paris" } ] }
```

Is it possible to write a mongodb aggregation that returns where each person is as of today:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name": "Homer", "currentLocation": { date: "...", "location": "Springfield" } }
{ "_id" : 2, "name": "Bart", "currentLocation": { date: "...", "location": "Houston" } }
{ "_id" : 3, "name": "Marge", "currentLocation": { date: "...", "location": "Washington" } }
{ "_id" : 4, "name": "Lisa", "currentLocation": { date: "...", "location": "Paris" } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this since mongo 3.2:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
  $match: {...}
}, {
  $set: {
    "currentLocation": {
       $arrayElemAt: [
         {$filter: 
           {input: "$itinerary", cond: {$eq: ["$$this.date", "present"]}}
         }, 
       0]
    }
  }
}, {
  $unset: {"itinerary": 1}
}]);
```

`$unset`and `$set` were added in 4.2, but you can use `$project` instead.